# Existe en PHP una instrucción parecida a xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName de javascript para rescatar una propiedad de un objeto

Tags: php, postgresql

Existe en PHP una instrucción parecida a **xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName** de javascript para rescatar una propiedad de un objeto.
Gracias.

Comment: Revisa la documentación de [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/es/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo mas claro de que es lo que quieres? que objeto tienes y que propiedad quieres rescatar?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.